# How do i get rid of xib after presenting it?

Tags: swift, xib

I am creating my own UIImagePicker Overlay and am using a Xib in order to display the overlay. Whenever I present the imagepicker, it seems to present twice, once when I call the main bundle to load the nib and the other when I explicitly present the imagepickercontroller. The main problem i'm having is when I dismiss the imagepickercontroller, the first one goes, which is great, but the underlying view of the xib still remains and doesn't go regardless of what i do.

I tried to convert the Objective-C example project for how to create a custom uiimagepickercontroller Apple has on their website into Swift. I'm not sure what I"m doing wrong, here is my code:

```
func showImagePickerForSourceType(sourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType) {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext
    picker.sourceType = sourceType
    picker.delegate = self

    if sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera {
        //gets rid of the out of the box imagepicker
        picker.showsCameraControls = false

        //loads the overlay xib for the camera
        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("OverlayView", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.overlayView.frame = (picker.cameraOverlayView?.frame)!
        picker.cameraOverlayView = self.overlayView
        self.overlayView = nil

        //makes the image capture screen the full screen size
        let screenSize: CGSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
        let cameraAspectRatio: Float = 4.0 / 3.0
        let imageWidth:Float = floorf(Float(screenSize.width) * cameraAspectRatio)
        let scale: Float = ceilf((Float(screenSize.height + 120) / imageWidth) * 10.0) / 10.0
        picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(CGFloat(scale), CGFloat(scale))

    }
    self.imagePickerController = picker
    self.presentViewController(self.imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Here is the code for a button on the xib dismissing the view. How can i fix this? Because i'm printing out the array of view controllers on the navigation stack, and it only shows one.

```
    @IBAction func goBack(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.imagePickerController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: In your XIB file, what outlets do you have connected on the file's owner?

Comment: thank you SO Much for that question, i realized I had connected the view to the file owner as well as a variable in the view controller. i wish i could give you the check mark, but you just cured my huge headache!

Comment: It was just a hunch, I'll post an answer so you can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have your view controller's `view` outlet connected to the view in your .xib file in addition to the `overlayView` outlet.  This would probably cause what you're describing.